# How do I SELECT specific names from a table, and display them in the body of an email?

Tags: python, mysql

The code below sends emails fine. However, it doesn't get the names from the MySQL table where `status = 'EXPIRED'`. I want to show in the body of the email the list of names of materials or a name of the material whose status is `EXPIRED` in MySQL table.

```py
def email_alert(subject, body, to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to

    user = "*******@server.com"
    msg['from'] = user
    password = "iuhfiudsfhe"

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, password)
    server.send_message(msg)

    server.quit()


try:
    email_list = "SELECT Email FROM users"
    mycursor.execute(email_list)
    emails = mycursor.fetchall()
    emails = [i[0] for i in emails]
    str(emails).strip('[]')

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    DB.rollback
    DB.close()

if matexpir <= d1:
    #Update material status on table.
    matstat = "EXPIRED"
    #GET material names from material table.
    try:
         matnames = "SELECT Name FROM material WHERE Status = 'EXPIRED'"
         mycursor.execute(matnames)
         #matids = mycursor.fetchall()
         #matids = [i[0] for i in matids]
    except Exception as e:
         print(e)
         DB.rollback
         DB.close()
    #Email alert for expired materials.
    email_alert("ALERT!", "your material {} has expired", emails).__format__(matnames)
```

Comment: Did you try un-commenting the two lines for `#matids = mycursor.fetchall()` and `#matids = [i[0] for i in matids]` ? Also, I guess you didn't write this code otherwise you'd know to add the `matids` to the `emails` so that they are both part of your email body.

Comment: I tried un-commenting the two lines and didn't work. None worked, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the "matnames", It is a pointer and not the string result.

You already did using the for to test. Just store the name of the products in a variable and concat THIS variable in the body of the e-mail, not the matnames.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood. Would you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Uncomment the two lines of matids and in the format__(matnames) change matnames to matids

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: uncomment the lines 

         #matids = mycursor.fetchall()
         #matids = [i[0] for i in matids]

and print(matids), what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I uncommented the two suggested lines. This still gave me errors until I changes the last line of code to:

email_alert("ALERT!", "your material {} has expired.".format(matids), emails)